# ANDROID: Disable EditTexts by a certain date and re-enable them after another date?

Tags: java, android, date, android-edittext

stackoverflow community.

As the question reads, I want to know if it's possible/how to disable an edittext field by a certain date (for example, you can input into the edittext until June 25th, after which it then becomes disabled) and then have it re-enabled after another date passes (you can once again input starting June 28th, for example).

I don't have any specific code to share as I haven't really developed anything yet; this question is one that really just came in my head while thinking how I would go about doing what I want to develop, and after searching online for awhile, I haven't found anything. What that means, however, is that I'm only looking for a general idea about how to do this (what methods would be used where etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Figure out if the current date is in an "enabled" range or "disabled" range. You can use Java classes like `Calendar` to help here.

Step #2: Call `setEnabled()` on the `EditText` based on the result of Step #1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Calendar class,basic example would be

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if(dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY){
            yourTextView.setText("it is sunday"); }
```